# How to make trigger on Debian to run script on folder's files change?

Tags: shell, triggers, debian

Do You know how can I make script in Jessie Debian, which will run when any of files in specific folder has changed ?
For example:

I have **/var/www** folder and few files in it. When i add new file i want to run

`composer dump-autoload -o` in another folder.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop containing your command and the `inotifywait` command on that directory. Example:

```
while true; do
    inotifywait -e create -r /var/www
    composer dump-autoload -o
done
```

Details: [`man inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I run Your script but it don't work exactly how I want because i create files on my host machine and vagrant synchronise them between each other and apparently inotifywait don't catch this "create event". Do You have any ideas, how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Try without `-e create`. Then it will catch everything.

Comment: Yup, that is an option :) but if i will make many changes it will run my command every time, when i make that change. In my opinion it won't be efficient :/

Answer (score 0):

You may use grunt or gulp task runners to watch for changes!
Those are much more useful during development than creating a custom solution.